# 'Strings' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#-4.0

I converted the following function from vb.net to c# but I cannot figure this out.

Error   4   The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current context

```
public string GetBetween(string StringText)
    {
        string functionReturnValue = null;

        string TMP = null;
        string FromS = null;
        string ToS = null;
        FromS = "<Modulus>";
        ToS = "</Modulus>";

        TMP = Strings.Mid(StringText, Strings.InStr(StringText, FromS) + Strings.Len(FromS), Strings.Len(StringText));
        TMP = Strings.Left(TMP, Strings.InStr(TMP, ToS) - 1);

        functionReturnValue = TMP;

        return functionReturnValue;

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.aspx) is a VB.net class.  You'd have to reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` assembly and use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace if you'd want to be able to use it.

It would be better if you just avoided using VB.net methods whenever possible.

```
public string GetBetween(string str, string start = "<Modulus>", string end = "</Modulus>")
{
    var startIndex = str.IndexOf(start);
    var endIndex = str.LastIndexOf(end);
    if (startIndex == -1 || endIndex == -1 || startIndex > endIndex)
        return str;
    return str.Substring(startIndex + start.Length,
                         str.Length - start.Length - end.Length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` in the header